# Manually sort in a NoSQL db

Tags: firebase, nosql

I'm new to the NoSQL world and I'm wondering if there are some known good patterns established for maintaining a manually sorted list.

More specifically, imagine the typical ToDo list application. At the top you have the `List` and under that you have each of the `Items`. I want the end user to be able to drag and drop the items. Therefore, I need to preserve this order for the next time I read these Items.

In a Relational DB I had a few ways to solve this, though none of those ways were that pretty. Maybe there is something better in the world of NoSQL? Not that it should matter, I'm using Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an integer field for each item that indicates its position in the list.  Update the values of the positions when user makes a change.

Comment: That is pretty much what I would have done in a Relational DB. Though I would have wrapped it in a transaction to ensure integrity. The fun is always the fact that all integers larger than the one that just got moved need to be updated.

Comment: firestore and realtime database also have transactions.

Comment: A common way to prevent the cascading updates is to stop thinking of them as integers, and just store them as floating point values. To move an item one down in the collection, set its field to the average value of the two documents it needs to end up between. The only think to be (really) careful with there is the granularity of floating point numbers, since you may run into limits after too many swaps. If that's a realistic use-case, set the field values for subsequent documents further apart, e.g. 1, 1001, 2001, 3001, etc.